# PIL Concentrate Many Images Fast

Tags: python, performance, python-imaging-library

I'm looking to make an "image quilt" or "image array" very fast using PIL. I'm looking for a method which takes in a list of images and image_per_row parameters and return a new PIL Image.

I currently have a working model of this, but it's not fast enough for 1k+ images at a time. I was thinking maybe using a numpy array would be faster? Would it be?

Here's what I have right now. Please note the image width will always be 1920, and the half parameter is there to make the final image size smaller.

Any fun ideas to optimize this or ways of doing it better would be appreciated :)

```py
from math import ceil
from PIL import Image

def _generate_array(
    images: List[Image.Image],
    images_per_row: int,
    half: bool = False
) -> io.BytesIO:
    frame_width = 1920
    padding = 3
    images_per_row = images_per_row

    img_width, img_height = images[0].size
    sf = (frame_width - (images_per_row - 1) * padding) / (images_per_row * img_width)
    scaled_img_width = ceil(img_width * sf)
    scaled_img_height = ceil(img_height * sf)

    number_of_rows = ceil(len(images) / images_per_row)
    frame_height = ceil(sf * img_height * number_of_rows)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (frame_width, frame_height), (0, 0, 0))

    i, j = 0, 0
    for num, im in enumerate(images):
        if num % images_per_row == 0:
            i = 0
        im.thumbnail((scaled_img_width, scaled_img_height))
        y_cord = (j // images_per_row) * scaled_img_height
        new_im.paste(im, (i, y_cord))
        i = (i + scaled_img_width) + padding
        j += 1
        
    if half:
        width, height = new_im.size
        width = round(width / 2)
        height = round(height / 2)
        new_im = new_im.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return new_im
```

Comment: It would be easiert for us to help if you provided [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Rather than reading all the thousands of images in sequentially and storing them all in a list at full size at the same time and thereby creating considerable memory pressure, you might consider loading and resizing with threads to get some I/O and resizing overlapped.

Comment: The generation of the thumbnails is certainly the slow part. This is because it is probably done sequentially on the CPU while this can be done on the GPU (dedicated for such task). The type of interpolation/aggregation have a strong impact on the performance: nearest is very fast, bilinear is fast, trilinear is slower, lanscos is very slow.